# sort n^2 numbers only with the function that can sort n numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

There is a function F() that can sort any n numbers, now there are n^2 numbers need to sort, how many times of calling F() you need at least ? (you can only call F() ).
I thought out a method like bubble sort, about O(n^2) times calling. Have any better way?

Comment: What would you do if you had `n+1` numbers?

Comment: Following @Alan Tam's answer/remark - are you allowed to use anything else? other function? comparisons? some DS?

Comment: Divide the numbers into three parts: the first n/2 numbers, the next n/2 numbers, the last one.  The problem just like compare three numbers

Comment: If the last comment was to answer my first one, then: **a**  you can't run `F()` on `n/2` numbers and **b** you'll need to merge the two halves of the array. I'd suggest to sort the first `n`, the swap the last number with some number in the middle, and then see where the difference is and run `F()` one lst time on that part.

Comment: Can't do any other operation that will change the position of number.

Comment: For you first comment, I mean run  F() on first n, then run F() on last n, then run F() on first.    Just like compare three numbers, isn't it?

Comment: Then the answer by @Lior Kogan is right.

Comment: Can you use the function that returns the position of specified number in the subarray?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need n(2n-1) steps (worst case). Here is an intuitive explanation:

Suppose there are 4 sorted groups of size (n/2) each. Let's call them A,B,C,D.
Also suppose that each of these groups is sorted, that the initial input vector is DCBA and that the final sorted vector should be ABCD.

In each single operation we can change the order of 2 groups (e.g. change BA to AB).

sorting DCBA requires the following steps:

DCBA --> CDAB (2 steps) --> CADB (1 step) --> ACBD (2 steps) --> ABCD (1 step)

Total steps: 6 = 4*3/2

Now support that you need to sort FEDCBA:

FEDCBA --> EFCDAB (3 steps) --> ECFADB (2 steps) --> CEAFBD (3 steps) --> CAEBFD (2 steps) --> ACBEDF (3 steps) --> ABCDEF (2 steps)

Total steps: 15 = 6*5/2

And so on....

To sort x blocks of size (n/2) each you'll need x(x-1)/2 steps (each step sorts n consecutive elements).

n² elements are 2n * (n/2) blocks, so you'll need (2n)(2n-1)/2 = n(2n-1) steps.

---

**Edit:**

**What if a single n-sorter (F) can sort arbitrary elements (not necessarily consecutive)?**

This turns out to a research-level problem related to [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). See also [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/Chapter%2027.pdf).

Take a look at this [recent paper by Shi, Yan, and Wagh](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0961v1.pdf):

> In this work, we propose an n-way merging algorithm, which generalizes
>   the odd-even merge by using n-sorters as basic building blocks, where
>   n (≥ 2) is prime. Based on this merging algorithm, we also propose a
>   sorting algorithm. For N = n^p input values, p + ⌈n/2⌉ × p(p−1)/2
>   stages are needed. The complexity of the sorting network is evaluated
>   by the total number of n-sorters. The closed form expression for the
>   number of sorters is also derived.

Comment: I agree. Exactly what I thought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the F() can only sort continuous numbers,  your solution is completely right.  But if F() can sort discontinuous numbers, how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Zero. You can write a new function that sorts `n^2` numbers, and you don't need to call `F()`. Is this cheating? I don't think so. It completely depends on what extra you are allowed to do except calling `F()`.

You can partition `n^2` numbers into `n` groups of `n` numbers and call `F()` on the each group, and then do a merging on `n` lists of `n` numbers. This is also a plausible solution, except you may still call it cheating.

There can be more specific solutions if you want to further put constraints to the question, but you have to spell out these constraints explicitly.

Comment: The first part is not constructive, The question did not stated you have to use `F()`, but it is obviously the purpose of the question. The second is one way of doing it, and not cheating, but how many times do you need? by my count,, it would be `(n^2)-n` times.

Comment: That depends on how you merge them. You can call `F()` (which is sub-optimal) and you can choose not to (say using a heap). But if you want to use a heap, you can do it in the first place, without even calling `F()`. That's why I think the question is vaguely defined.

Comment: Constraints  :  you can't do any other operation that will change the position of number.

Comment: @newSolar Assuming the numbers are stored in an array `A[n^2]` and `F()` is the only way to mutate the array, I would manually run a sorting algorithm on `A` to figure out for each number at position `x` the correct sorted location `p(x)`. With one `F()` on `n` different positions on `A` I can get at least `floor(n/2)` of them into place. So I need roughly `2n` calls to `F()`. I don't think this is what you need.

Comment: If you want to add a further constraint that I cannot read the array `A` at all and I need to blindly make calls to `F()` (i.e., the same sequence applies to any input `A`), then it is a real challenge. I don't have a solution in mind yet, but I don't see it plausible within `n^2` calls to `F()`.

Comment: @AlanTam thanks for your opinion, Follow your solution, if I have known the position of numbers,  Is  2n the minimum number to sort all ? Can it be smaller ?

Comment: Proving an absolute minimum is quite hard. My solution: In each iteration, you always pick `x`, `x+1`, ... `x+floor(n/2)-1`, as well as the `floor(n/2)` numbers that will go into these places. So you have to it for `x=0`, then `x=floor(n/2)`, etc. This will take either `2n` or `2n+1`, or a bit more for very small values `n`.